# ORACLE DATABASE IMP could not read dmp file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have a Oracle 11g Database Dump as a Full.dmp file.

I try to load this dump inside another Databaseserver on my workingsystem.

I tried the following commmand inside the CMD of windows 10:

```
imp system/password full=y file=testfile.dmp
```

i've placed the file inside the correct folder.

this is my error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>imp system/password full=y file=testfile.dmp
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Do Nov 12 14:25:14 2015
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

IMP-00002: failed to open testfile.dmp for read
Import file: EXPDAT.DMP >
```

have you a idea where my fault could be?

It seems like the Oracle Databaseserver hasn't the right chmod, but i'm on windows so how should i configure the file securitysettings?

SOLUTION:

I've just open the cmd Console with adminrights and it worked.

Comment: Are you certain the dumpfile is located in c:\windows\system32? The error message suggests it isn't or you have the name wrong.

Comment: Thank found the the fault, just started the cmd promt with admin rights and it workes.

Comment: That seems like a strange and potentially dangerous place to create your own files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure opening command line with admin rights (open as administrator).
2. try to change file location from C to other drive (permission issue).
3. Use this command: 
   imp userid=userInstance/passwordInstance@localhost:1521/xe file=D:\fileName.dmp FULL=Y